# How to pass parameter to Eval() in Link Button Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton, asplinkbutton

ASP Declaration:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="edit item" onclick="'AddItem.aspx?catid=<%# Eval("CollectionID")%>'"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I get Error:
The server tag is not well formed.

what the problem with LinkButton decloration?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: quote problem.. may be.. Just a thought why dont raise event in code behind and do response.redirect since thats what you are doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="edit item" onclick='AddItem.aspx?catid=<%# Eval("CollectionID")%>' />
```

I removed extraneous quotes around the attribute value for `OnClick`.

However, `OnClick` expects a delegate, not a URL. Either use a hyperlink or switch to an event handler.

```
<a href='AddItem.aspx?catid=<%# Eval("CollectionID")%>'>edit item</a>
```

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.oncommand.aspx) shows how to pass an argument to an event handler from a link button. Instead of using `OnClick`, you can use `OnCommand` and set the `CommandArgument` property.

*In Markup*

```
  <asp:LinkButton id="lnkEdit" 
       Text="Edit Item"
       CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CollectionID")%>'
       OnCommand="lnkEdit_Command" 
       runat="server"/>
```

*In Codebehind*

```
protected void lnkEdit_Command( object sender, CommandEventArgs e )
{
    // evaluate e.CommandArgument and do something with it
}
```

I favor using a URL versus a command event handler whenever possible as it eliminates a comparatively expensive postback.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass param in these way.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="edit item" 
PostBackUrl='AddItem.aspx?catid=<%#Eval("CollectionID")%>&catname=<%#Eval("CollectionName")%>' />
```